# Unable to install "mysql2" gem on Linux (CentOS)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rubygems

I am unable to install the "mysql2" gem on my CentOS linux machine.

I recently install mysql following the following tutorial: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/installing-mysql-server-on-centos

When I try to download "mysql2" gem I get the following log:

```
[root@vc2cmmka035538n ruby]# gem install mysql2
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'mysql2' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: mysql
```

**Environment info:**

- Rails 3.2.3
- ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
- gem -v 1.8.24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From their github page, quoted

> This gem links against MySQL's libmysqlclient C shared library. You may need to install a package such as libmysqlclient-dev, mysql-devel, or other appropriate package for your system.

So, you might wanna install those packages first. Then you can even manually compile the gem if you still face the problem. 
https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2

If mysql repo is disabled on your system, here is the link about installing them

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-repo-excerpt/5.6/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html